# Visualforce PDF : display footer only on one page, and at the bottom of the page

Tags: visualforce, css, html, pdf

I have a VF page render as pdf like that (to simplify) :

```
<div class"mainContent" style="page-break-after:always;">
  <div>
     <table>a table with more or less lines (dynamic)</table>
  </div>
  <div class="footer" style="position:fixed; bottom: 0px;">my footer</div>
</div>
<div class="lastPage">the last page</div>
```

I put `style="page-break-after:always;"` on the first div (mainContent) so the last page is always on a new page (it works).

The footer is fixed at the bottom of the pages, but it is also displayed onthe last page, and I don't want it to be displayed on the last page.

I want it to be displayed on the first page if the table is short enough. 
If the table contains a lot of lines that create a new page with the table divided on two pages for exmple, I'd like the footer to be displayed only on the second page (at the end of the table, but at the bottom of the page)

Is that possible ?

Blockquote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensuring the footer doesn't appear on the last page should be possible with `@page` and Named Pages in your CSS. Unfortunately there's no `:last` psuedo-selector for `@page`, otherwise that would get the job done.

First, add some CSS for your last page:

```css
div.lastPage {
    page: lastPage; 
    /* This assigns the name, basically, if this class appears, then this is a "lastPage" page*/
}
```

Then add a `@page` rule:

```css
@page lastPage {
    .lastPage {
        display: none;
    }

    @bottom-center {
        content: ''; 
        /* displays nothing at the bottom of the page if you have a page rule for 
        this zone on other pages */
    }
}
```

Without seeing the CSS you have on the page you might need to do one or the other above.

Some helpful resources on page rules in CSS:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20170320220445/https://www.antennahouse.com/CSSInfo/CSS-Page-Tutorial-en.pdf
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page

Comment: I havn't more css than what I put in my example. I tried to add your css snippet to my VF page but there is no differences, the footer is still displayed on the last page

Comment: It sounds like `position:fixed; bottom: 0px;` on your footer div is pulling it to the bottom of _all content_, making it always below the lastPage div.

Comment: Yes I remove that part and the footer is no more on the last page, but it is no more in the bottom of the firt page too (the footer is displayed just after the content of the page, and not at the bottom)

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21043407/5174170

Part of the issue is that `fixed` is meant for an entire viewport (which doesn't really exist when printing) so it sounds like it's treating all pages as the viewport making it always go to the bottom of the last page. To get around that you will likely need to set the container div to `position: relative` and use `position: absolute` for the footer. Because you want the container to stretch the height of the pages. This does not sound very simple. See if you could use `@page` and `@bottom-content` to position instead?

Comment: thank you the link provided the answer : I can now display the footer on the bottom of the first page. But If my table contains many rows, the last rows are displayed on top of the footer instead of going on another page. Do you know how I can force the table to continue to another page after for example 20 rows ?

Comment: You will need to get creative. For example, in your table, if you can get a class on the last row of the table you could do something similar to what I wrote in my answer with assigning a name to the page that the last row is on. Once it's got a name, you can specify the `@bottom-content` of that named page. Make sense?

Comment: ok thank you, I will try like that ! Thanks for the answers